# Is it possible to set the VoiceMailNumber?

Tags: android, voicemail

It is possible to read the voice mail number by using this: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getVoiceMailNumber()

But is it possible to set it yourself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not without some extended hacking. It's definitely not something that Android wants you to be able to set. If I were dead set on trying, I would start by looking at `com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone();` and `com.android.internal.telephony.Phone.setVoiceMailNumber` and trying to invoke them through reflection. It's not something that I recommend bothering trying to do really.